# Why is the change in potential energy equal to the final potential energy with a reference point of infinity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

If there was a charged particle at some arbitrary point called A and the particle at A will never move, if there was another particle at position B of equal sign moving toward A at some velocity V. The particle will stop at some position C between A and B. By the conservation of energy, the energy of the moving particle at point A is equal to the energy at point C. Hence...

$$E_0=E_f$$
$$\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2=\Delta U_f$$
This last line I have a hard time conceptually understanding.
The first half makes intuitive sense since it is saying that the change in electrostatic potential energy is equal to the negative work done by moving the particle against the force of distance B-C. The last part of this equation shows the result after integrating with respect to r, which also happens to be the formula of the potential energy at a point infinitely away. Why is that so? I'm confused why the change in potential energy is equal to the final potential energy relative to infinity.
$$r=B-C$$
$$\Delta U_f=-\int_B^C\frac{kq_1q_2}{r^2}dr=\frac{kq_1q_2}{r}$$
[image]

Comment: You're applying the limits in the final equation incorrectly. It is $kq_1q_2(r_B^{-1}-r_C^{-1})$ which is *not* the same as $kq_1q_2/(r_B-r_C)$...

Comment: @lemon I was confused since the final result seemed to match the formula for the potential electrostatic energy formula. So it is just a coincidence in this case only(the photo) that the change in PE is equal to that formula?